# Line up differently spaced data when using two axis in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot an x-axis (bot) that corresponds to values with another x-axis (top), against some data. I want the top and bot axis to refer to the same data point. The following code demonstrates my problem

```
clc; clear all;

botXaxis = [2.54   1.61  1.00  0.61  0.37];
topXaxis = [159283 97232 59354 36232 22117];
data =     [10     10    10    10    10];

hplot = plot(botXaxis,data);
set(hplot,'Linestyle','none','Marker','o'); 
ax1 = gca;
ax1.XScale = 'log';
ax1.XTick = fliplr(botXaxis);
ax1.XLim = [min(botXaxis) max(botXaxis)];
ax1.XTickLabel = fliplr(botXaxis);
hold on
plot1 = plot([botXaxis(3) botXaxis(3)],get(ax1,'YLim'),'--','color',[0 0 0]);

ax1_pos = ax1.Position;
ax2 = axes('Position',ax1_pos,'XAxisLocation','top','YAxisLocation','right','Color','none');
ax2.XScale = 'log';
set(ax2, 'XTickMode', 'manual');
ax2.XLim = [min(topXaxis) max(topXaxis)];
ax2.XTickMode = 'auto';
ax2.XTick = fliplr(topXaxis);
hold on
plot1 = plot([topXaxis(3) topXaxis(3)],get(ax1,'YLim'),'-','color',[0 0 0]);

% Fix double tick marks 
set(ax1,'box','off');
```

If you run it this plot appears:

[image: plot]

I have drawn the straight lines to see if the data lines up correctly. As you can see they do not. I am wondering if there is a way to fix this? The values for `data` should line up with both `topXaxis` and `botXaxis`.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you those points should match? `(59354-22117)/(159283-22117)` does not equal `(1-.37)/(2.54-.37)`. To me, it is correct that `59354` (top) is slightly to the left than `1` (bottom). To make them aligned, you would need to change the values in `botXaxis` or in `topAxis`

Comment: Thanks for your comment @LuisMendo. I see the problem now. In this case I am a bit confused about how to proceed. Because the values in top X axis have been calculated from bot X axis and are just in different units, and the data is per point (top or bottom X axis)...

Comment: Perhaps it's just a matter of numerical precision. For example, `topXaxis = botXaxis*59354` would produce the desired matching

Comment: @LuisMendo I see now, that works well. I can use the scale by multiplication, that works perfectly. Thanks a lot. I guess not so much a MATLAB question, I thought that some plotting tricks may have sorted this out, such as being able to force them into position.

Comment: You could also do this: use `topXaxis = botXaxis` (maybe that's what you mean by "force them into position") and then set the `XTickLabel` property of `ax2`: `ax2.XTickLabel = fliplr({'159283' '97232' '59354' '36232' '22117'});`